# Block matrix rank inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

I encountered an exercise (not my homework)

> Let $A,B,C$ be matrices and
> $$
>  M=\begin{pmatrix} A & C \\ 0 & B \end{pmatrix}
>  $$
> then
> $$
>  \mathrm{rank}~M\ge \mathrm{rank}~A+\mathrm{rank}~B
> $$
> and the equality holds if and only if there exist matrices $X,Y$ such that $C=AX+YB$.

I can work out the inequality (by proving the existence of a nonvanishing minor of size $ \mathrm{rank}~A+\mathrm{rank}~B$) and the "if" part (by multiplying block elementary matrices). However, I failed to handle the "only if" part. I am aware of [a paper by W.Roth](https://community.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-03/S0002-9939-1952-0047598-3/S0002-9939-1952-0047598-3.pdf) that deals with the problem, but the method seems to be tedious and out of my reach. In addition, this reminds me of the Sylvester's Inequality, but I cannot proceed further from that.

I wonder if there is a simpler approach, perhaps in the language of linear transforms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if $A$ and $B$ are 'diagonal', in particular all zero except the first $r_1$ and $r_2$ respective diagonal entries are $1$?   Can you show $C= AX + YB$ in this case?